# Arrow diagrams using packages

Tags: diagrams, arrows, trees

Is there a way to draw a diagram like such using only default provided packages?

[image: Arrow diagram]

The part that I'm trying to figure out is creating an arrow that points above an element, like the right-most arrow in the diagram. Would this be achievable through packages only, or do I have no other choice but to resort to programmes like Inkscape?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried [tikz](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/diagrams/)? [Something like this](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/borrowers-and-lenders/) or [this](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/er-diagram/) looks like your diagram.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You may easily do that with  `pstricks`, and more specifically with `pst-node`.

Comment: @Peter -- maybe the answer below will show the away

Comment: I could definitely try tikz. Thank you!

Comment: @Bernard I've never heard of `pstricks` before. Will definitely check out. Thank you!

Comment: It's a sort of interface between LaTeX and Adobe Postscript. It's simpler to compile pstricks code with `xelatex` (pdflatex doesn't  have the necessary computation engine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, hobby, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
          %\draw [help lines,  red!30] (0,0) grid (6,6);
        
        \draw (0,0)-|(3,5)-|node[pos=.25, fill=white](x){\huge X}(0,0);
        \node[below=2cm of x, circle, fill, draw, inner sep=2pt, label=left:x\textsubscript{2}] (x2) {};
        
        \path
        (1.5,2.5)coordinate(z0)
        (2,2)coordinate(z1)
        (3.1,2.2)coordinate(z2)
        (3.2,5.4)coordinate(z3)
        (2.5, 5.5)coordinate(z4)
        (2,5.4)coordinate(z5)
        ;
        \draw[->, -Latex](x2) to (z0)..(z1)..(z2)..(z3)..(z4)..(z5) to (x);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect. I'll see if I can try the same with multiple arrows. Thank you!